# AngularJs a tag not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When we use the static html which is working code its working fine. But when we make it dynamic using angular ng-repeat its not working. Please give your views on the code pasted below.

//Not Working

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="accordian-screen-place">
<ul style="padding:10px;">
    <li class='has-sub' ng-repeat="option in selectedItem.Option">
        <a><span class="uppercase">{{ option.name }}</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="attOption in option.AttributeOption">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1">
                <label><h3 class="h3-check">{{ attOption.name }}</h3></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

//Working

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="accordian-screen-place">
<ul style="padding:10px;">
    <li class='has-sub'>
        <a><span class="uppercase">{{ option.name }}</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1">
                <label><h3 class="h3-check">{{ attOption.name }}</h3></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script>
$('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
$('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('sss');
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }     
});
```

Comment: When you say "not working" - what is not working? Give more details. Also, post a fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: Can you add some part of controller also. Not really able to figure out what you are trying to do. Or create a fiddle instead.

Comment: This is actually a menu thing for dropdown. When we say not working on click its options are not showing because we are using ng-repeat for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet does not working because lists are rendered by angular after your jQuery code is running. Since AngularJS may decide to redraw the list items (with `ng-repeat`) any time something is changed in the scope, it is better not to use `bind`, but `on` with 3 parameters (which is the same as `live` in old jQuery versions). Besides of it AngularJS has special directives for odd/even staff, so it's better to use them instead of writing extra code in jQuery. After a bit of modifications your code may be something like this:

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/R5L5qcGtmNsUYwdvk1ow?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="accordian-screen-place">
  <ul style="padding:10px;">
    <li class="has-sub" ng-repeat="option in selectedItem.Option">
      <a>
        <span class="uppercase">{{ option.name }}</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="attOption in option.AttributeOption" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
          <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" />
          <label>
            <h3 class="h3-check">{{ attOption.name }}</h3>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click', '#cssmenu > ul > li > a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('sss');
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }     
});
```